# Get element of select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML select drop down that is populated from a JQuery get request. You can view that here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjVjra

I am trying to get the following example element of the selected value on each change.

> `<small class="text-muted">ETH</small>`

I have tried the following but that would just bring back the name of the selected option, which is not what I am after.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
        alert( $(this).val()
    });
});
```

Is it possible to drill to the inner code of the selected option and retrieve that data.

Thanks

Comment: Actually what you posted here wouldn't do anything since there's a syntax error. Second, you're required to post a [mcve] here in your question, not on a third party site. Finally, your question is unclear and I see no `<small>` element even in your codepen.

Comment: Where is the `<small class="text-muted">ETH</small>` you refer to? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Points taken, I will try to do better next time. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the question fits with the CodePen, but you could try something like this:

```
$("#cryptos :selected").attr("data-subtext");
```

Comment: Sorry for not making my question clear, somehow you managed to decipher what I was trying to say. I appreciate it so much I can now continue with my project - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `<small>` tags in the HTML, as their shouldn't be because only `<option>` and `<optgroup>` are valid elements in a `<select>`.

If you meant `<option>`, you can use the `:selected` pseudo-class to get the actual `<option>` element instead of just its value:

```
// in select onchange where this == select element
$(this).find(':selected'); // the option element
```

Also, note that your CodePen example doesn't actually have the dropdown named `#dropdown`, so just make sure you use the appropriate selector.

Comment: Thanks for answering and pointing out errors in my code, I am learning and this helps